# Modal with AngularJS isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create an AngularJS directive to work with a modal window and I can't figure out how to isolate the scope. My goal is to have a modal window to add a new location. I want the directive to populate the modal with any needed data from the parent scope and handle the save button click. I got this working using the parent scope, but I have not been able to get it working with isolated scope.

The parent controller has a locations property, which in this case is the only parent property I need. The newLocation object should be isolated from the parent scope. When I add the isolated scope, the name input is not populated and the click handler doesn't fire. The scope declaration only allows @, =, and & properties so I can't augment it there, and adding properties in link has no effect.

Directive:

```
        angular.module('pw').directive('addLocationModal', [
        'appApi', function (appApi) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    locations: '='
                },
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.newLocation = {
                        name: 'xxx'
                    };
                    scope.saveLocation = function () {
                        alert('save location');
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add-location-modal" add-location-modal>
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                <span>&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add Location</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="newLocation.name" required />
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveLocation()">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or plnkr?

Comment: If you need to keep scope isolated, you should pass initial value using prefix @ and use prefix & to let parent scope know the changes made to location on save function

Comment: I created a Plunker -- http://plnkr.co/edit/FxtSPHR3QFJOd0PTnMiI but it doesn't work even without the isolated scope and I'm out of patience with this.

Comment: be far simpler by getting rid of bootstrap.js and using `angular-ui-bootstrap`. No need to re-invent the wheel

Comment: Interesting project but I don't want to fully commit to Angular.

Comment: last comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application that has pages which require a lot of client-side interaction with a REST API. I've got this working well as a demo using knockoutjs for client-side data binding but I like Angular's syntax better. What I'm bumping into is that Angular is a complete framework and it's difficult to use pieces of it. I don't want to mix normal Bootstrap markup with pure Angular directives. Basically I just want data-binding, dependency injection and form validation from Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to move div

```
<div class="modal-dialog">...
```

to the template of the directive

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl : 'view.html',
    scope: {
       locations: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         scope.newLocation = {
             name: 'xxx'
         };
        scope.saveLocation = function() {
           alert('save location');
        };
    }
};
```

in `view.html`

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
   .....
   .....
</div>
```

in `index.html`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add-location-modal" add-location-modal>

</div>
```

`directive` html should compile against the directive scope (to bind the scope data and the functions to the view more likely bind the directives like to the scope like `ng-click`, `ng-model` if that not compiled against the desired scope its not going to bahave as we expected), here you have no directive template and you assume `html` between the directive div in `index.html` behaves as the `directive html` but its actually its not.

move the inner content of the `<div class="modal fade" id="add-location-modal" add-location-modal>` to the template of the directive will solve this. Because directives `ng-model` and the `ng-click` are compiled against the directive scope not it's parent scope.

here is the simple [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/YUICAUupcrKUuUHxXb99?p=preview)

**update - solution for your first comment**

you can compile the `html` between directive div and append to same element in directive `compile` function as,

```
compile: function(tElement, tAttr, transclude) {
  var contents = tElement.contents().remove();
  var compiledContents;
  return function(scope, iElement, iAttr) {
    if (!compiledContents) {
      compiledContents = $compile(contents, transclude);
    }
    compiledContents(scope, function(clone, scope) {
      iElement.append(clone);
    });
  };
},
```

and move your scope properties to directive `controller` function

```
 controller: function($scope) {

     $scope.newLocation = {
        name: 'xxx'
     };

     $scope.saveLocation = function() {
        alert('save location');
     };
}
```

here is the updated [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/IMlmqPbOY8Z8jgJQmXBo?p=preview)

Comment: In my case the modal template is an ASP.NET Razor partial view that is rendered on the page. So, a directive with isolated scope only has access to DOM elements declared in template or templateUrl? I'm very impressed that you were able to type this answer and create a Plunker in less time than I was able to figure out how to use Plunker. :-)

Comment: Hi @JamieIde i updated the answer please have a look :), Yeas directive will compile the `html` define in directive `template` or `templateUrl` at this compile phase directives like `ng-click`, `ng-model` bind with the scope. And lol yeas plunker proves some boilerplate to start a angularjs plunker. click on the down arrow which placed right to the menu item `new` and choose a angularjs :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I had two problems with Plunker: 1) The first library choices are pre-release versions and 2) I couldn't find an option to add Bootstrap's JavaScript components and had to locate a CDN.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have got it.  The modal is not working with an open and close, but I forked **@K.Toress**'s plunk and I think I got the isolate scope working.

http://plnkr.co/edit/8DwJqc?p=preview

The important pieces.

1. You need to use a controller as well as a directive.  You need the scope in the controller to start with.

   ```
   app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.locations = [{name: "loc1", level: 1}, {name: "loc2", level: 2}]
   });
   ```
2. When you define the directive, the directive scope will have a `directiveLocations` object.

   ```
   scope: {
     directiveLocations: '=locations-attr'
   },
   ```
3. It gets the name of this object from the locations-attr attribute on the element, which is "locations".

   ```
   <div class="modal" add-location-modal locations-attr="locations">
   ```
4. So now we have mapped the controller $scope.locations to the directiveLocations in the directive scope.
5. For saving the location back to the parent controller scope, you simply append to the directiveLocations list since it is now the same as the parent $scope.locations.

   ```
   var tempLocation = {
     name: scope.newLocation.name,
     level: scope.newLocation.level
   }
   scope.directiveLocations.push(tempLocation);
   ```

*I'm not sure why I had to create a new object here.  There was something strange about adding the same object back into the parent scope.*

Comment: I had a little trouble with Angular and bootstrap modal.  Removing the "fade" class (and thus the animation) helped.